# Reading and displaying a file

Tags: c++, file

I'm having issues displaying this file. I'm trying to create a file and display it in an output screen. But the getline is not working. It keeps giving me a "getline undeclared" in line 40. I've tried chaning things and nothing I do works. What is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()

{

  char filename[] = "Hello.txt";

  string line = "Hello, this is my output file";

  ofstream OutFile;

  OutFile.open(filename);

  if(OutFile.fail()) // check for successfully open ,

   {

     cout << "file named can not be found \n";

     exit(1);

   } 

     OutFile << line;

     if (OutFile.is_open())

       OutFile.getline(line);

    OutFile.close();

     system("pause");

}
```

Comment: I've already tried that it doesn't work either

Comment: "Doesn't work" is pretty vague. What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline()` is a free function, not a member function. The member function version is for raw character arrays and since you're using `std::string`, the free function is the appropriate one.

```
std::getline(Outfile, line);
```

Also note that `std::getline()` only works with objects of type `std::istream`, and since you're trying to perform *input* your `Outfile` object shouldn't be `std::ofstream`. <strike>Please change it to the input file stream *`std::ifstream`*.</strike>

Change `Outfile` to `std::fstream` which is a bidirectional file stream.

Comment: I changed it to fstream and used getline as " getline(Outfile, line);" and it's still not working. It's saying "OutFile undeclared"

Comment: 36 C:\Users\s346lab\Documents\Untitled1.cpp `Outfile' undeclared (first  use this function)

Comment: also 2 C:\Users\s346lab\Documents\Untitled1.cpp:42 [Warning] no newline at end of file

Comment: @jon You declared your variable as `OutFile` but you wrote it as `Outfile` (lowercase `f`) on the `getline` call. Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: I see it now. What I don't get is how do i get it to display on an output screen? All that happens is it says to press any key to continue. The file is created however

Comment: @jon You didn't print the string `line` to output. Try doing `std::cout << line` before `system("pause")`.

Comment: @jon You also might need to flush the output before performing input, so on the `OutFile << line` call, do `OutFile << line << std::flush`.

Comment: I already tried that it still says the same thing without displaying the string

Comment: @jon Have you tried changing `OutFile << line` to `OutFile << line << std::flush`?

Comment: @jon I'm trying to test out your code. One moment. :)

Comment: @jon You need to put this line `OutFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);` after `OutFile << line << flush`